# The complex form of Hamilton canonical equations

Tags: classical-mechanics, coordinate-systems, hamiltonian-formalism, complex-numbers, phase-space

I found an excerpt on page 171 of "The variational principles of mechanics" written by Cornelius Lanczos stated that

> If, however, the conjugate variables $q_k$, $p_k$ are replaced by the complex variables  $$\frac{q_k+ip_k}{\sqrt{2}}=u_k$$ and $$\frac{q_k-ip_k}{\sqrt{2}}=u_k^*,$$ then the double set of canonical equations $$ \dot q_i=\frac{\partial H}{\partial p_i}, \qquad\dot p_i=-\frac{\partial H}{\partial q_i}$$ can be replace by the following single set of complex equations $$\frac{du_k}{idt}=-\frac{d H}{d u_k^*}.$$

I did not understand that why shall we introduce the complex conjugate of $u_k$ and the coefficient $\sqrt 2$. It seems to me that the equation $$\frac{du_k}{idt}=-\frac{d H}{d u_k}$$ with $$u_k=q_k+ip_k$$ can already fulfill the task. Could you please tell me why my thinking is wrong?

P.S. I found another link ([Relationship between complex analysis and Hamilton's canonical equation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/426920/)) related to this problem but not exactly the same.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. We need the complex conjugated variable$^1$ $\bar{z}$ because the Hamiltonian $H(z,\bar{z})$ is typically *not* [holomorphic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holomorphic_function) in $z$.
2. The normalization of the [CCR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_commutation_relation)$^2$
   $$\{z,\bar{z}\} ~=~-i \tag{1}$$
   explains the $\sqrt{2}$-normalization in
   $$ z~=~\frac{q+ip}{\sqrt{2}}.\tag{2}$$
3. Recall that Hamilton's equations can be written in terms of the Poisson bracket
   $$\dot{z}~=~\{ z, H\}~=~\{ z, z\}\partial H + \{ z, \bar{z}\}\bar{\partial} H. \tag{3}$$
   In the last equality in eq. (3) we used that the Poisson bracket $\{ \cdot, \cdot\}$ is a first-order differential operator wrt. its second entry.
4. We can now derive the complex form of Hamilton's equations
   $$\dot{z} ~\stackrel{(1)+(3)}{=}~-i\bar{\partial}H.\tag{4}$$

--

$^1$ To connect to OP's notation, use $z\equiv u$.

$^2$ Quantum mechanically, the Poisson bracket (1) should be replaced with $(i\hbar)^{-1}$ times the corresponding commutator
$$[\hat{z},\hat{z}^{\dagger}] ~=~\hbar \hat{\mathbb{1}}, \tag{5}$$
in accordance with the correspondence principle between classical and quantum physics. Here the operator $\hat{z}$ and the Hermitian adjoint operator $\hat{z}^{\dagger}$ are [an annihilation and a creation operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creation_and_annihilation_operators), respectively. Hamilton's equations (3) are then replaced by [Heisenberg's equations of motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenberg_picture)
$$i\hbar\dot{\hat{z}}~=~[ \hat{z}, \hat{H}].\tag{6} $$

Comment: Is there really an interest in writing the Hamilton equations in complex form?  What gives?

Comment: Yes. The complex Hamiltonian formulation is used in e.g. coherent state path integrals.

Comment: Notes for later: Hamiltonian Lagrangian $\quad L_H=i\bar{z}\dot{z}-H$. Symplectic potential 1-form $\quad \vartheta=i\bar{z}\mathrm{d}z$. Symplectic 2-form $\quad \omega=i\mathrm{d}\bar{z}\wedge \mathrm{d}z$