# Complex Hamiltonian formalism

Tags: homework-and-exercises, hamiltonian-formalism, complex-numbers, phase-space

> *If
> $x_k=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(q_k+ip_k)$ and $\bar{x_k}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(q_k-ip_k)$
> Show that the Hamilton's equation of motion can be expressed in the form:
> $\frac{dx_k}{dt}+i\frac{\partial H}{\partial\bar{x_k}}$=0  where $i = \sqrt{-1}$.*

Here I am not getting what should be the $H$ function in the first place, considering $q_k ,p_k$ as the coordinates,how can I find the $H$ function?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/495709/2451

Answer (score 0):

He doesn't require you to find $H$, he require you to rewrite the Hamilton equations in the new shape, giving the standard equations as grantend in the classical formulation.